# SOAP UI mock server groovy scripting

Tags: soap, wsdl, soapui, mockserver

Currently i am having two SOAP projects(A and B) imported from WSDL files.
I created a mock server with one of the projects(A) and from my application i am able to call the mock server and get response.
Now i want to go further and try to invoke a request to another service situated in another project(B) when a soap operation is called in mock server project(A).The Project B is a call to another application.
Can i write groovy scripts to do this?

so whenever an operation A1 is called in project A after a time lapse a request needs to be sent from project B which might be an operation B1.

Here actually i am trying to simulate an external application using soap ui.
I understand i can do it by writing a program using java but thought i could do this in short time using soap ui.

As question i wanted to know if my thought is right of using soap ui or should i go do it through another tool or writing a java app.

Comment: Could you please frame your question correctly , its confusing. Correct me You have SoapUI Project A,B both are of SOAP WSDL type and in Project A , You have mock server . Now you want a facility when Project A/ or your code makes a call to Project A mock server on mock operation A1 , then in mock server you want to make a call to Project B on a operation B1. is that right .

Comment: you are right i want to call an operation on project B from mockserver running on Project A.